# Split multiple user registration profiles into separate pages

Tags: drupal, profile, registration, user-account

I have three profiles as well as a custom form that I show on drupal's user/register/ page. I want to split the registration form into first Drupal's user info, then the first profile, and the rest of the profiles on the third page with my custom form as well.
Illustration:

```
    Page 1                       Page 2                     Page 3
+------------------------+   +-----------------------+  +-------------------------+
|                        |   |                       |  |                         |
|  +------------------+  |   |  +-----------------+  |  |  +------------------+   |
|  |Drupal Account    |  |   |  | Profile 1       |  |  |  | Profile 2        |   |
|  |Registration      |  |   |  |                 |  |  |  |                  |   |
|  |                  |  |   |  |                 |  |  |  |                  |   |
|  |                  |  |   |  |                 |  |  |  +------------------+   |
|  |                  |  |   |  |                 |  |  |                         |
|  |                  |  |   |  |                 |  |  |  +------------------+   |
|  |                  |  |   |  |                 |  |  |  |Profile 3         |   |
|  |                  |  |   |  |                 |  |  |  |                  |   |
|  |                  |  |   |  |                 |  |  |  +------------------+   |
|  |                  |  |   |  |                 |  |  |  +------------------+   |
|  |                  |  |   |  +-----------------+  |  |  |Custom form       |   |
|  +------------------+  |   |                       |  |  +------------------+   |
+------------------------+   +-----------------------+  +-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to do this using Webform (which allows for multipage forms) and utilising Rules to trigger the Drupal User creation. There was a [blog](https://civicrm.org/blogs/petednz/creating-drupal-users-made-easy-single-or-multiple-contacts-civi-imports-and-webforms) Fuzion wrote sometime ago outlining such an approach.

In order to ensure that people visiting user/register end up on this form use the [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module to push them through to the relevant node.

Comment: According to the civicrm wiki, the webform integration is not easily embedded on the user/register or account pages which is what I need.

Comment: use Redirect and set user/register to point to a webform